# Vector control method

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I am working on a motor control project.

[image]

In the above picture there is an SVPWM generator.

It is my understanding that the SVPWM generator block can be an SVPWM or a sinusoidal PWM or Sinusoidal PWM and third harmonic injection, etc.

I want to confirm if my understanding is correct or not.

And one more question: is the modulated waveform of PVPWM a double hump and is the modulated waveform of SPWM third harmonic injection also a double hump? In my understanding, the output voltages of the two technologies SVPWM and SPWM third harmonic injection are the same. Is this correct?

Comment: There is a good article by Microchip that describes the principles of SVM, and shows the "double hump" waveform you mention. I believe that is due to "overmodulation" which allows a somewhat higher voltage than would otherwise be possible for sine wave PWM duty cycles from 0% to 100%. https://www.microchipdeveloper.com/mct5001:space-vector-modulation

Answer (score 1):

Space vector PWM (SVPWM) is a Clarke transform based technique that generates a PWM directly from the alpha-beta frame. Since it is commonly used, you can easily find more details on the principle and implementation of the algorithm.
The particularity is that it results in a voltage waveform that optimizes the use of the DC bus for the same reason as a third harmonic injection (the peak voltage is lower for the same fundamental amplitude and the third harmonics are cancelled in the current for a three-phase system).
Using SVPWM, the voltage shape comes from the injection of a triangular wave known as min/max injection as shown in the following figure.
[image: sinusoidal third harmonic injection and SVPWM waveform]
Here is a Simulink example to implement min/max injection on a 3p sinusoidal signal:
[image]
So to answer the last question, the voltage waveform is not exactly the same between SVPWM and a sinusoidal third harmonic injection but the results are close.
I would be curious to know if someone can bring complementary comparisons between these two signal waveforms.